# Smooth action $G\curvearrowright M$ induces smooth action $TG \curvearrowright TM$

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, lie-groups, group-actions, linearization

**Setup:** Let $G$ be a Lie group acting smoothly on a manifold $M$ by a map
$$ A\colon G\times M \to M.$$

The derivative of the mutliplication $\mu\colon G\times G \to G$ defines a group structure on $TG$. Then the derivative of $A$ defines a $TG$-action on $TM$
$$ DA \colon TG \times TM \to TM. $$

**Questions:**

1. How would you call this construction?
2. Do you know a book that discusses properties of this?
3. Is $DA$ a proper action if $A$ is?

**Thoughts:**

- The group $TG$ is isomorphic to the semi-direct product of $G$ and $\mathfrak g$ wrt the Adjoint action
- ([Proper action on $M$ induces proper action on $TM$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710179/proper-action-on-m-induces-proper-action-on-tm))